# Singleton-comparison suggestion by pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

For the given code

```
def greater(n):
    if n > 3:
        res = True
    else:
        res = False

    return res

a = greater(5)
print(hex(id(a)))
print(hex(id(True)))

b = True
print(hex(id(b)))

if  a == True:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

`pylint` suggests `pylint_example.py:16:4: C0121: Comparison 'a == True' should be 'a is True' if checking for the singleton value True, or 'a' if testing for truthiness (singleton-comparison)`

`a is True` will check [both address and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)
and I [cannot assume immutable variables will have the same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657554/why-two-list-having-exactly-same-data-shows-different-memory-address-in-python-w)

Thus, changing `a == True` to `a is True` may lead to incorrect results (`a` and `True` may have different addresses in memory). Why does `pylint` suggest that?

Though

```
print(hex(id(a)))
print(hex(id(True)))

b = True
print(hex(id(b)))
```

part gives consistent results. I am not sure if that would work in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean identity == True vs is True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276610/boolean-identity-true-vs-is-true)

Comment: Your whole function should be `return n > 3`. Everything else is unnecessary.

Comment: Not sure. I am keep on asking in the comment of answers. Nephanth's answer is closest. I am testing py39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`True` and `False` are unique singletons, not immutable. If `a` has the value `True`, then `a` and `True` **do** have the same memory address.

Source: [PEP-0285](https://peps.python.org/pep-0285/#specification) and [In Python are the built in constants True and False unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48897561/11542834)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any source can confirm the unique entry will have the unique address in memory?

Comment: @Chungji what do you mean that they will have unique addresses in memory?

Comment: Yes. That is what I would like to know

Comment: @Chungji `True` is a singleton, so *all* references to `True` point to the same object/memory address. I don't see how "unique memory addresses" is related.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is all reference to singleton to the same memory address in https://docs.python.org? Where can I find it?

Comment: @Chungji the closest I can quickly point you to is [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool), which guarantees they are the only instances of `bool`, saying "The `bool` class is a subclass of `int` (see Numeric Types — int, float, complex). It cannot be subclassed further. Its only instances are `False` and `True`."

Answer (score 0):

[PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) claims that correct way is to use if variable giving following example

```
if greeting:
```

and claims that

```
if greeting == True:
```

is wrong and

```
if greeting is True:
```

is worse.

Comment: To my limited knowledge, PEP8 is a style guide, rather than in-principle right/wrong. What is the difference between `if greeting:` and `if greeting == True:`? Sorry for my stupid understanding.

Comment: if greeting:: This condition checks the truthiness of the greeting variable. If greeting is any non-empty value, the condition if greeting: will evaluate to True. On the other hand, if greeting is an empty string, 0, None, or an empty container, the condition will evaluate to False.

if greeting == True:: This condition explicitly checks if the value of greeting is exactly equal to True. It compares greeting with the boolean value True using the equality operator ==. It will evaluate to True only if greeting holds the value True itself.